# Css: Remove the bottom border where the ancestor tag and list item meet

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the `<a>` tag, I need the border between the `<a>` and the dropdown menu to disappear. As shown in the image below, the border where the first level `<a>` meets the first level `li` should disappear when hovering over the `<a>` tag.

[image: Required Shape]

```css
.main-navigation {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  align-content: center;
}

.firstLevelul{
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.firstLevela{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font: normal small-caps 100 20px/1.8em 'Helvetica Neue';
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 1.5em;
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}

.firstLevela:hover{
  color: #D9D9D9;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
}

.secondLevelul{
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.secondLevela{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.secondLevelli:hover{
  background-color: violet;
}

.firstLevelli:hover > .secondLevelul{
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}
```

```html
        <nav class="main-navigation">
            <ul class="firstLevelul">
                <li class="firstLevelli"> <a href="#" class="firstLevela"> hi </a>
                    <ul class="secondLevelul">
                        <li class="secondLevelli"> <a class="secondLevela" href="#"> Edit</a></li>
                        <li class="secondLevelli"><a class="secondLevela" href="#">Reset Passwor
                            </a></li>
                        <li class="secondLevelli"><a class="secondLevela" href="#">Disable User</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push the popped up content behind the HI text, and make the border bottom transparent on hover. Giving it a background color of white will make sure, div's top border isn't visible when it is colliding with HI.

```css
.main-navigation {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  align-content: center;
}

.firstLevelli:hover > .firstLevela{
  border-bottom : 1px solid transparent;
}

.firstLevelul{
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.firstLevela{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font: normal small-caps 100 20px/1.8em 'Helvetica Neue';
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
}

.firstLevela:hover{
  color: #D9D9D9;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.secondLevelul{
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.secondLevela{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.secondLevelli:hover{
  background-color: violet;
}

.firstLevelli:hover > .secondLevelul{
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navigation">
            <ul class="firstLevelul">
                <li class="firstLevelli"> <a href="#" class="firstLevela"> hi </a>
                    <ul class="secondLevelul">
                        <li class="secondLevelli"> <a class="secondLevela" href="#"> Edit</a></li>
                        <li class="secondLevelli"><a class="secondLevela" href="#">Reset Passwor
                            </a></li>
                        <li class="secondLevelli"><a class="secondLevela" href="#">Disable User</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: but when I hover over the dropdown, the border returns

Comment: updated answer (added .firstLevelli:hover selector)